# Sign outgoing mails with DomainKey on exim4 and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, exim, domainkeys

I just installed Exim 4.73 on Ubuntu using apt-get.  I was able to easily integrate DKIM signing because of it's integration with Exim.  I'm having some trouble with DomainKeys support.  Most of the online documentation recommends compiling Exim with the DomainKeys library which I'd rather not do.  Is there an easier way to have my Exim installation sign outgoing messages with a DomainKey signature?  I noticed a package called dk-filter but couldn't find much documentation about it online.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, if you have DKIM working, why the requirement to support DomainKeys as well? My understanding is that DomainKeys is now regarded as historical whereas DKIM was effectively a later version of DomainKeys (including some identity bits, hence the 'IM' part) and had become a standard.

Comment: Yahoo still checks DomainKeys, as do some other ISPs, I believe.

Comment: Correct, +1 ensnare!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "one button way" of doing that. Experimental with lib or you can use DKIMproxy  that works with DKIM and DomainKeys to sign outgoing mail.

Comment: Second dkim-proxy. Signing sure eats a lot of cpu though :-).